# Docker for Mac. docker run -d -p 80:80 --name webserver nginx shows another container with this name. but docker ps shows empty list

Tags: docker, containers, invisible

I am learning "Docker for Mac"

`$ docker run -d -p 80:80 --name webserver nginx`

docker: Error response from daemon: Conflict. The name "/webserver" is already in use by container 728da4a0a2852869c2fbfec3e3df3e575e8b4cd06cc751498d751fbaa75e8f1b. You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name..

But when I run

`$ docker ps`

It shows no containers listed.

But due to the previous error message tells me that there is this container 728da....

I removed that container

`$ dockder rm 728da4a0a2852869c2fbfec3e3df3e575e8b4cd06cc751498d751fbaa75e8f1b`

Now I run this statement again

`$ docker run -d -p 80:80 --name webserver nginx`

It is working fine this time.

And then I run `$ docker ps`, I can see this new container is listed

```
$ docker ps
```

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                         NAMES

3ecc0412fd31        nginx               "nginx -g 'daemon off"   19 seconds ago      Up 17 seconds       0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 443/tcp   webserver

Note:

I am using "Docker for Mac".

But I had "Docker Box" installed on the Mac before. I don't know if that is the invisible "webserver" container comes from.

Comment: The other container must have stopped. See `docker ps -a` and you should see your container named `webserver`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As activatedgeek says in the comments, the container must have been stopped. `docker ps -a` shows stopped containers. Stopped containers still hold the name, along with the contents of their RW layer that shows any changes made to the RO image being used. You can reference containers by name or container id which can make typing and scripting easier. `docker start webserver` would have restarted the old container. `docker rm webserver` would remove a stopped container with that name.

You can also abbreviate the container id's to the shortest unique name to save typing or a long copy/paste. So in your example, `docker rm 728d` would also have removed the container.

Answer (score 0):

The Docker Getting Started document asks the learners trying two statements first.

`docker run hello-world`

and

`docker run -d -p 80:80 --name webserver nginx`

I was wondering why I can run

`docker run hello-world`

many times but if I run

`docker run -d -p 80:80 --name webserver nginx`

the second time, I got the name conflicts error. Many beginners would be wondering too.

With your help and I did more search, now I understand

`docker run hello-world`,

we did not use --name, in this case, a random name was given so there will be no name conflicts error.

Thanks!